# Reading data from XML into a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code that creates a temporary table from XML:

```
INSERT INTO @tblPostitions(PosId,OtherId,Status)
SELECT 
T.P.value('(PosId)[1]','INT'),
T.P.value('(OtherId)[1]','INT'),
T.P.value('(Status)[1]','TINYINT'),
FROM @XML.nodes('General/Positions/Position') AS T(P)
```

It works like a loop.

I have this situation. I would like the value to be changed when creating a new line in `@tblPostitions`

When `Status = 1`, change it to `2` and if different, leave it unchanged

XML:

```
<General>
  <Positions>
      <Position>
          <PosId>1</PosId>
          <OtherId>2</OtherId>
          <Status>1</Status>
      </Position>
      <Position>
          <PosId>2</PosId>
          <OtherId>3</OtherId>
          <Status>2</Status>
      </Position>
      <Position>
          <PosId>3</PosId>
          <OtherId>6</OtherId>
          <Status>1</Status>
      </Position>
  </Positions>
</General>
```

Comment: Provide the XML (at least needed data) - to test it, in a way to copy and paste. And the expected

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage I added example XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
INSERT INTO @tblPostitions(PosId, OtherId, Status)
SELECT 
    T.P.value('(PosId)[1]','INT'),
    T.P.value('(OtherId)[1]','INT'),
    IIF(T.P.value('(Status)[1]','TINYINT') = 1, 2, T.P.value('(Status)[1]','TINYINT'))
FROM @XML.nodes('General/Positions/Position') AS T(P)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do with temporary table or XML here. It is just selecting different value based on a condition.

To make it easy to understand, I'd rather do it with a `Case` follows:

```
Select PosId,OtherId,
    Case When StatusId = 1 then 2 Else StatusId End as [Status]
 from
(
    SELECT 
    T.P.value('(PosId)[1]','INT') as PosId,
    T.P.value('(OtherId)[1]','INT') as OtherId,
    T.P.value('(Status)[1]','TINYINT') as StatusId
    FROM @XML.nodes('General/Positions/Position') AS T(P)
) Q
```